# Server started in 'Rescue' mode

Tags: ssh, rescue-mode

We have bough a server and we are using for our website, today I received an email from the provider that your server has started into **Rescue** mode and they sent to me a temporary password to login through PuTTY.

Any one can teach me what to do? When I log in with SSH, I get `root@rescue` but I don't know how to set Grub...

I have TRIED some suggestion from google but I couldn't find the solution.

I see some suggestion how to repair it using boot CD, but I don't have the server here and I can't use that method, any other method please?

Here is configuration from `/etc/default/grub/`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to clarify which Ubuntu release the server is and whether the system is running on virtual hardware (e. g. inside of a container or virtual machine) or "bare metal"? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Some VPS service support guideline for this kind of problem with WebGUI.
[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/is-there-a-way-to-boot-into-recuse-mode), you can see sample.

If there is no way to do like above. Another way is to modify `grub` menu.
If your familier with `vi` editor. If not try with your desired editor.

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

Find the following line.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
```

In my VPS, that line is like this.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=tty1 console=ttyS0"
```

Confirm your edit with `cat /etc/default/grub`.

After that update grub.

```
sudo update-grub
```

And then reboot your server.

```
sudo reboot
```

If still you are in rescue mode, edit your answer with your with `/etc/default/grub` detail to verify more by others.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment , i followed your suggestion but when i type sudo update-grub i get one error 

/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `aufs'.

Comment: type command `df -h` and please comment what is output.

Comment: Hi, i get result with long characters and this reply form don't allow me to paste all the text, tell me for which line u are interested to know?

Comment: you can use to post with https://paste.ubuntu.com/ and can share link.

Comment: Hi, here is the link : https://paste.ubuntu.com/23821662/

Comment: Remounting may not help grub problem because of your are on a remote Virtual server. So lets try with other way.

Comment: [LInk](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-recover-from-file-system-corruption-using-fsck-and-a-recovery-iso) according to this guide, try with `fsck`. Type `fsck` in your terminal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51992/discussion-between-h0feer-and-san-lin-naing).

Comment: here is what i get : 


root@rescue:~# fsck
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
root@rescue:~#